# Use native framework inside Unity in standalone build

Tags: ios, macos, unity-game-engine, frameworks

I have a Unity project that uses a native ios framework from C# scripts. When I compile it for iOS app (`.ipa`), everything works fine.
I want to compile it for macOS, too, that means `Standalone` build.
To enable that, I check `Standalone` in import settings:

[image: Screenshot]

Then build the app for Standalone platform:

[image: Screenshot]

It builds an app, but it is unable to access native framework, and I don't see it inside package contents:

[image: Screentshot]

What am I missing?

Comment: sounds like it could be a unity bug, did you try updating or grabbing a patch release for your current version?

Comment: says it's up to date: `2018.2.5f1`

Comment: What framework and where did you put it in your project ? A screenshot is even better

Comment: This is an SDK written in Objective c (unfortunately I can't share details here). The structure is: `Project-Name/Assets/SDK-Name/Plugins/iOS/SDK.framework`

Answer (score 0):

> unable to access native framework, and I don't see it inside package
>   contents:
>
> The structure is:
>   Project-Name/Assets/SDK-Name/Plugins/iOS/SDK.framework

There are two issues:

**1**.The directory you put the plugin.

You put the iOS plugin the `Plugins/iOS` folder which works fine.

For Mac OSX, you put it in the `Assets/Plugins` folder. This is also where you put plugins for Windows and Linux.

**2**.You must [convert or build](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html) the plugin or framework into a bundle. This bundle is what you should place in the `Assets/Plugins` folder.

Comment: How can I build an existing project into a bundle? In the guide it is only said how to create it from scratch

Comment: I also have my C# files that call the SDK in `Plugins/SDKName/iOS/SomeFile.cs`. When running the game, in the console I see `EntryPointNotFoundException: method_name
  at (wrapper managed-to-native)`.

Comment: Your `SomeFile.cs` should be in the `SDKName` folder not `SDKName/iOS` because you want to use it on Mac too. The files that should be in  `SDKName/iOS`  are the native files. The `EntryPointNotFoundException` means that it could not find the function. I do not have your code so there's really nothing  I can do. I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49795660/3785314). It has the error described there and how to fix it